# Fetch values after Inner Join in SQL

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have the following tables:

```
rooms - id, room_name, room_type
room_type - id, type_name.
```

Example of this tables:

```
Rooms- id=1 , room_name = "101" , room_type = "1"
room_type - id=1 , type_name = "Deluxe".
```

Now I am trying to fetch this table Rooms where i want it to display room type name instead of room_type id.

Like in above case I want output like:

```
1,101,Deluxe.
```

I have tried this join but it failed:

```
SELECT * from rooms r INNER JOIN room_type t on t.id = r.room_type
```

I get the following error:

```
Warning: mysqli_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given
```

Please help

Update:

Here is the php fetch code:

```
$getquery =mysqli_query($connection,"SELECT * from rooms r INNER JOIN room_type t on t.id = r.room_type");

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($getquery)){

    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td> </td>";
    echo "<td>" . $row['room'];
    echo "<td>" . $row['room_type'];
```

Comment: The error message has nothing to do with the query.

Comment: Please update your question to include the PHP that calls `mysqli_fetch_array` - that is where the error is so *that's* the code we need to see. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: OK, and where's the rest of the code? e.g. where's `$getquery` coming from? Please include **[a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)** so that we have *all* the information we need to help.

Comment: where is `myqli_query()` before while loop?

Comment: @BeingSunny updated!

Comment: `myqli_query``is failing and returning false which is the boolean thats referenced in the error message. Your query looks ok, so  have you confirmed that the connection is set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

It seems your query is failing and returning a false value.Below is sample/Dummy code

```
$sql = "SELECT * from rooms r INNER JOIN room_type t on t.id = r.room_type";
$result = myqli_query($connection,$sql);
while($r = mysqli_fetch_array($result)
{
    /// your code here
}
```